# Joins in Hibernate

Tags: oracle, hibernate, join, hql

I have Two table having parent-child relation.

1. Party with columns (**PARTYSEQ**,PARTYID...)
2. PartyContact with columns ( PARTYCONTACTSEQ, **PARTYSEQ**,CONTACTTYPECD.... )

Scenario : *For one record of party there might be no record or max 3 records in PartyContact.*

Desired Output in **HQL** : Fetch **a** party if no records present in partyContact ( which can be done using join) **but** if multiple records are present in partyContact against that party then show only one of them.* \

Example 
**PARTY TABLE / Data object**

- **1620** INDIVIDUAL  sdfdsf  sdfdsf

**PARTYCONATCT TABLE / Data object**

- 1332 **1620**            RESIDENTIAL
- 1333 **1620**            OFFICE
- 1334 **1620**            MOBILE

problem is to consider this three records in party contact as one.

My query :

```
SELECT partyDO.firstName1,partyContactDO.contactTypeCd  FROM PartyDO partyDO left outer join partyDO.listPartyContactDOList partyContactDO 
where partyDO.id=1620
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is on the entities strucuture.

You can get your result in two ways:

The first:

Add a formula in Party entity, like this:

```
<property name="partyContact" formula="
        (select pc.id from partycontact pc where pc.fk_party = id limit 1"
type="string"></property>
```

so when you'll run your query:

```
SELECT P FROM Party P
```

You'll get party and the first PartyContact

The second:

Add a collection of PartyContact in your Party entity.

So when you'll run your query:

```
SELECT P FROM Party P
```

You can get the first element of PartyContact collection.